I have been trying to launch an application for about 4 days in Django to Render
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 277, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect    
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net" (35.212.103.87), port 52584 failed: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: I


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 581, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 89, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 63, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner    
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 316, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 292, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner    
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 274, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__      
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner    
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner    
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 277, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\DEV\DJANGO\dealer_project\env\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect    
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net" (35.212.103.87), port 52584 failed: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: I

I am trying to upload the application with a database in Postgress, it is a crud with images and that info is added from the admin, then sent to the index.html through a separate component

received invalid response to SSL negotiation but you've not bothered to say anything about the SSL configuration at either end of the connection.

Why are you attempting to connect to a Railway (rlwy.net) database from what I assume is your local development environment?
